# How to set bottom navigation bar position fixed in compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I wanna the **navigation bar to be at the bottom of the page using jet compose** (material 3)
[image]

How to set the bottom navigation bar position fixed in compose

Here is my sample code for the navigation bar

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.ArrowBack
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Favorite
import androidx.compose.material3.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import io.material.compose.ui.theme.Purple40


@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun NavigationBarDemoSample(navController: NavController) {
    var selectedItem by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    val items = listOf("Songs", "Artists", "Playlists")


    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            CenterAlignedTopAppBar(
                title = { Text("Navigation Bar") },
                Modifier.background(Purple40),
                navigationIcon = {
                    IconButton(onClick = { /* doSomething() */
                        navController.navigateUp()
                    }) {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Filled.ArrowBack,
                            contentDescription = "Localized description"
                        )
                    }
                },
                
            )
        },
        content = {

            NavigationBar {
                items.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
                    NavigationBarItem(
                        icon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Favorite, contentDescription = null) },
                        label = { Text(item) },
                        selected = selectedItem == index,
                        onClick = { selectedItem = index }
                    )
                }
            }

        }
    )

}
```

Here is my output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your `Scaffold` adding the `NavigationBar` in the **`bottomBar`** parameter instead of the `content` parameter:

```
Scaffold(
    topBar = /* ..  */ ,
    bottomBar = {
        NavigationBar {
            items.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
                NavigationBarItem(
                  /** ..... */
                )
            }
        }
    }
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Scaffold**
Compose provides convenient layouts for combining Material Components into common screen patterns. Composables such as Scaffold provide slots for various components and other screen elements.

**Screen content**
Scaffold has a generic content trailing lambda slot. The lambda receives an instance of PaddingValues that should be applied to the content root — for example, via Modifier.padding — to offset the top and bottom bars, if they exist.

Read more: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/material#scaffold

```
package compose.material.theme

import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Favorite
import androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api
import androidx.compose.material3.NavigationBar
import androidx.compose.material3.NavigationBarItem
import androidx.compose.material3.Scaffold
import androidx.compose.runtime.*

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun NavigationBarDemoSample() {
    var selectedItem by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    val items = listOf("Songs", "Artists", "Playlists")
    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = {
            NavigationBar {
                items.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
                    NavigationBarItem(
                        icon = {
                            androidx.compose.material.Icon(
                                Icons.Filled.Favorite,
                                contentDescription = null
                            )
                        },
                        label = { androidx.compose.material.Text(item) },
                        selected = selectedItem == index,
                        onClick = { selectedItem = index }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    ) {
        // Screen content

    }
}
```

[image: Navigation bar]